# Malloc vs Creating a Data Structure

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

What is the use of malloc, instead of just creating a structure within a c function? For example, this is the model code for creating a node in a Binary Search Tree.

```
void insertBSTNode(BTNode **node, int value)
{

    if (*node==NULL)
    {
        *node=malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
        (*node)->item =value;
        (*node)->left =NULL;
        (*node)->right = NULL;
        return;
    }
    if ((*node)->item > value)
        insertBSTNode(&((*node)->left), value);
    else if ((*node)->item <value)
        insertBSTNode(&((*node)->right), value);
    else
    {
        printf("Already exists in the BST\n");
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

I tried to do something similar, but instead created the struct instead like this:

```
void insertBSTNode(BTNode **node, int value)
{
    if ((*node) == NULL){
        BTNode insert;
        insert.item = value;
        insert.left = NULL;
        insert.right = NULL;
        (*node) = &insert;
        return;
    }   
    
    else {
        int Nodeitem = (*node)->item;
        if (value>Nodeitem){
            insertBSTNode(&((*node)->right),value);
            return;
        }

        if (value<Nodeitem){
            insertBSTNode(&((*node)->left),value);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But Nodeitem would always be the address instead. Why does malloc work in this case? When I use
`BTNode insert`, is that not similar to using malloc instead whereby `&insert` just points to the memory location? Should I be using malloc instead then?

Comment: Your second version creates dangling pointers, so your code will invoke *undefined behavior* (and generally do weird things)

Comment: May I know why it creates dangling pointers? What should I do instead to correct the second version.

Comment: In your code `insert` is an automatic variable (defined in a bloc or function and not static). It will reach its end of life at the end of the bloc where it is defined and any pointer pointing to it will be said *dangling* after that. Because trying to use an object after it has reached its end of life is explicitely Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for you help! I assumed (very wrongly) that memory was somehow more permanent that the variables within the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `BTNode insert;` you are using memory from the stack. This is fine as long as you are only working with this data inside of the `insertBSTNode` function, but once you leave the function, the stack memory can (and will) be used by other functions. `malloc` on the other hand uses heap memory, so you can use the allocated memory outside of the function which called `malloc` without the risk of it being overwritten by other functions. You also have to keep in mind that memory allocated with `malloc` must be manually freed once it is no longer needed by your application.

Comment: _"you are using memory from the stack"_: this statement is most of the time correct, but formally there is no stack in the C language. The statement should be _"`BTNode insert;` declares a local variable that will whose life will end as soon as the program leaves the scope."_

Comment: @Jabberwocky, you are correct in that the c standard doesn't demand that local variables are implemented using stack memory. But it is also possible to argue that the lifo nature of variables with automatic storage makes them by definition a stack. Therefore I would say that *"you are using memory from the stack"* is a good mental model even if maybe not technically correct.